# Argument in mark method of ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: java, bytearrayinputstream

I tried the following code to understand the working of `mark()` method of ByteArrayInputStream.

```
class tryByteArray  
{  
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception  
    {  
        byte[] buffer={71, 69, 69, 75, 83};  
        try(ByteArrayInputStream obj=new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer))  
        {  
            System.out.println("\nChar "+(char)obj.read());  
            obj.mark(0);  
            System.out.println("Char "+(char)obj.read());  
            System.out.println("Char "+(char)obj.read());  
            System.out.println("Char "+(char)obj.read());  
            obj.reset();  
            System.out.println("\nChar "+(char)obj.read());  
            System.out.println("Char "+(char)obj.read());  
          }  
    }  
}
```

It gave the following output:-

```
Char G
Char E
Char E
Char K

Char E
Char E
```

But when I changed the argument of `mark()` method to 1,2 or any number it still shows the same output. Can someone explain to me the working of `mark()` method?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#mark(int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#mark-int-):

> Note: The readAheadLimit for this class has no meaning.

**Edit:** Also take a look at [the source code](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.java#L246).